# Grafico se modifica tamaño al ocultarlo y mostrarlo con div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Agregue un grafico Chart de Google y hasta eso todo bien, se muestra el grafico en grande, pero el problema inicia cuando meto el grafico en un div y le pongo la propiedad (display:none;) esto para que me muestre el grafico una ves que presione cierto boton.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues que le pongo en css (display:none) si funciona bien el codigo si se oculta y muestra pero el problema que al mostrarse se hace pequeño, ya le modifique las medidas al grafico y no, se muestra en la imagen como se reduce de tamaño. El unico codigo que me afecta es el de css todo lo demas esta bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas propiedades me muestra una ves que inspecciono se modifican tanto el "width" como el "height" como se muestran en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el código, creo que al encapsular la grafica dentro de un div y este supongo que esta dentro de un div container, pues esta siendo empujado por los demás elementos del container, tienes que ver bien como estructuras tus divs y para mayor compresión del funcionamiento abre el inspector de elementos y ve como se comportan, y en el mismo inspector puedes ir añadiendo propiedades o cambiándolas y ver el resultado.

Comment: Me imagino que el problema debe ser que para que se vuelva a mostrar estás haciendo que display sea "block" o algún otro valor que no era el que tenía el gráfico originalmente. Te recomiendo que le hagas click derecho, eligas la opción "Inspeccionar", y luego te fijes que valor tiene cuando tiene el tamaño original. Te dejo el link en donde podés ver los valores que puede tomar [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display). (Probablemente sea "flex" o "grid").

Comment: Ya lo solucione, ya entendi el problema al utilizar el Javascript  $("#graficos_indicadores").click(function(){
    $("#id_del_div").toggle();
    
 se cambiaban no solo el display sino que los demas valores, la solucion hice que el boton en lugar de mostrar el div mejor me mande a otra pantalla donde tengo los graficos mostrados sin ocultar. gracias por sus comentarios